# Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, java-time

I'm parsing logs from different sources, I'm extracting datetime string from log. Now I want to convert it into java ZonedDateTime.

Problem here is, I don't know exact datetime format, I just know that, string will be ISO-8601 compliant. So I want to write function like :

```
    /**
     * @param _dateTime : any ISO 8601 format , e.g 1. %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%s%z => 2014-05-25T08:20:03.123456Z , 
     *                    e.g 2. %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%s => 2014-05-25T08:20:03.123456, e.g 3. %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s%z => 2014-11-08 15:55:55.123456Z, 
     *                    e.g 4. %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s => 2014-11-08 15:55:55
     * @return Instance of ZonedDateTime if conversion successful
     * @throws DateTimeParseException
     */
    private ZonedDateTime parse (String _dateTime) throws DateTimeParseException  {
        // Magic here.
    }
```

What is best way to do it in java ?

Comment: What do you mean you don't know the format? ISO 8601 datetime is a format.

Comment: Your javadoc seems to suggest that using a space between the date and the time is an acceptable substitute for the letter T. That is not ISO 8601. ISO 8601 always uses T as the delimiter. ["*Separating date and time parts with other characters such as space is not allowed in ISO 8601*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations)

Comment: Like i mentioned in method description it could be like 2014-05-25T08:20:03.123456 or 2014-11-08 15:55:55.123456Z or  2014-11-08 15:55:55  etc ...

Comment: Your 4th example, `2014-11-08 15:55:55`, is not ISO 8601 compliant.  ISO 8601 requires a `T` to denote the start of the time part as in your 1st and 2nd example. Same problem with the 3rd example.

Comment: When the string ends with a `Z` for UTC, clearly you should get a `ZonedDateTime` in UTC. When it doesn’t, which time zone do you want? It requires a time zone to construct a `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s non-trivial alright. Most of the magic is in the following formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter
        = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
                .appendPattern("['T'][' ']")
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
                .appendPattern("[XX]")
                .toFormatter();
```

This formatter accepts

- A date like `2014-05-25`.
- Either a `T` or a space (or both or neither, but I count on exactly one of them being in your string). The square brackets denote optional parts of the format. The single quotes denote literal parts and cause the `T` not to be interpreted as a pattern letter.
- A time of day. `ISO_LOCAL_TIME` accepts seconds with and without a decimal fraction.
- An optional UTC offset like `Z` (for zero) or `-0600`.

We also need a time zone for the cases where we haven’t got an offset in the string. For example:

```
private static final ZoneId defaultZone = ZoneId.of("America/Curacao");
```

What your method still needs to do is distinguish between the cases with and without UTC offset. The form with offset can be parsed directly into a `ZonedDateTime`. The one without cannot, so for it we need to parse into a `LocalDateTime` and convert.

```
/**
 * @param dateTime : any ISO 8601 format , e.g 1. %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%s%z => 2014-05-25T08:20:03.123456Z , 
 *                    e.g 2. %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%s => 2014-05-25T08:20:03.123456, 
 *                    e.g 3. %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s%z => 2014-11-08 15:55:55.123456Z, 
 *                    e.g 4. %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s => 2014-11-08 15:55:55
 * @return Instance of ZonedDateTime if conversion successful
 * @throws DateTimeParseException
 */
private static ZonedDateTime parse(String dateTime) {
    // Little magic here.
    TemporalAccessor parsed = formatter.parseBest(dateTime,
            ZonedDateTime::from, LocalDateTime::from);
    if (parsed instanceof ZonedDateTime) {
        return (ZonedDateTime) parsed;
    } else {
        return ((LocalDateTime) parsed).atZone(defaultZone);
    }
}
```

Let’s try it out. I have used your four examples plus one that I added between the 1st and the 2nd.

```
    System.out.println(parse("2014-05-25T08:20:03.123456Z"));
    System.out.println(parse("2014-05-25T10:20:03.123456+0200"));
    System.out.println(parse("2014-05-25T08:20:03.123456"));
    System.out.println(parse("2014-11-08 15:55:55.123456Z"));
    System.out.println(parse("2014-11-08 15:55:55"));
```

Output:

> ```
> 2014-05-25T08:20:03.123456Z
> 2014-05-25T10:20:03.123456+02:00
> 2014-05-25T08:20:03.123456-04:00[America/Curacao]
> 2014-11-08T15:55:55.123456Z
> 2014-11-08T15:55:55-04:00[America/Curacao]
> ```

As an aside prefer `OffsetDateTime` over `ZonedDateTime` for your strings with a UTC offset. The code will be the same except you will need a further conversion `.toOffsetDateTime()` after `atZone(defaultZone)` in the case where you don’t get an `OffsetDateTime` directly from parsing. A `ZonedDateTime` is for a date and time with a time zone like Europe/Prague. An `OffsetDateTime` is for a date and time with a UTC offset. As I mentioned, `Z` is an offset of 0 from UTC.

Edit: Arvind Kumar Avinash’ notes in a comment are useful and important enough to deserve to be in the answer proper: **Some notes for the future visitors:**

1. Replacing `[XX]` with `[XX][XXX]` will also cater to the offset like +02:00.
2. Date-time parsing/formatting types are Locale-sensitive and therefore, it's always advisable to use it with the applicable locale e.g. `.toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)` instead of `.toFormatter()`.
3. You can use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` if you want the `ZoneId` of the JVM to be picked up automatically.

Comment: **Some notes for the future visitors:** (1) Replacing `[XX]` with `[XX][XXX]` will also cater to the offset like `+02:00` (2) Date-time parsing/formatting types are `Locale`-sensitive and therefore, it's always advisable to use it with the applicable locale e.g.  `.toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)` instead of `.toFormatter()` (3) You can use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` if you want the `ZoneId` of the JVM to be picked up automatically.