# Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to epoch on KitKat

Tags: java, android, iso8601

I have the following ISO8601-compliant string:

```
2024-03-25T11:34:15.000Z
```

I need to convert it to java Date. I found the following solution:

```
Date date = Date.from(Instant.parse("2024-03-25T11:34:15.000Z"));
long epoch = date.getTime());
```

However, this requires at least Android Oreo. I need a converter that works down to KitKat. Any idea?

Tried following solutions but had the same issue:

1. [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to ZonedDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887575/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-zoneddatetime)
2. [Converting string to date using java8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665464/converting-string-to-date-using-java8)

I also found a solution by using JAXB but I read somewhere that it bloats my APK by 9MB! With it, the solution could be this simple:

```
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(iso8601Date).getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Why not `Instant.parse("2024-03-25T11:34:15.000Z").toEpochMilli()`?

Comment: Because Instant.parse() requires Android Oreo as well.

Comment: Well `java.time` exists because those old classes are buggy. You might like to investigate whether Joda can do it for you

Comment: Your existing code -- and code using java.time in general -- will work on older Android versions when you use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) (or if for some reason you don’t want that, there’s also [ThreeTen Android Backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)).

Comment: Don’t use `Date`. In your example code it’s a needless detour. Use just `Instant.parse("2024-03-25T11:34:15.000Z").toEpochMillis()` to get the milliseconds since the epoch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert String Date to Date in Android (Java/Kotlin) without having to deal with Call requires API level 26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191152/convert-string-date-to-date-in-android-java-kotlin-without-having-to-deal-with)